# Inject BasicDataSource at runtime with spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, datasource, jdbctemplate

I use spring to access to a database :

- XML Spring context :

  `<bean id="ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">...</bean>
   <bean id="jdbcTmp" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="myDao" class="MyDao">
       <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTmp" />
   </bean>`
- Code :

  `System.out.println("There is : " + new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml").getBean("myDao").countRowsInTheDB() + " rows in this source";`

It's simple and it works good. But I want to choose between different databases at runtime according to a variable.

Something like :

`ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
 int rows1 = ctx.getBean("myDao", "dataSource1").countRowsInTheDB();
 int rows2 = ctx.getBean("myDao", "dataSource2").countRowsInTheDB();`

What is the simpliest way to do that ?

I want to create an XML configuration for each source :

```
 <bean id="myDao1" class="MyDao"><property name="data" ref="jdbcTmpForDataSource1" /></bean>
 <bean id="myDao2" class="MyDao"><property name="data" ref="jdbcTmpForDataSource2" /></bean>
```

And write the code :

```
 int i = getDataSourceIndex();
 ctx.getBean("myDao" + i).countRowsInTheDB();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a second datasource, jdbc template, dao :**

```
<bean id="ds2" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">...   </bean>
<bean id="jdbcTmp2"   class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
 <property name="dataSource" ref="ds2" />
</bean>
<bean id="myDao2" class="MyDao">
 <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTmp2" />
```

**Create a bean, that is a list of all datasources**

Just autowire it in, spring will inject the list

```
@Autowired List<DataSource> dataSources;
```

In your code iterate over the list and do whith the datasourceswhatever you want.